# Ambiguous error when accessing Dictionary key/values

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, swift4

I am using Swift 4, AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON to consume some data from an API.

I created a generic wrapper for AlamoFire

**MyApiClass**

```
  func post(_ product: String = "", noun: String, verb: String, onCompletionHandler: @escaping (Bool, JSON) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post,  parameters: package, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {
            response in

                let json : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if let r = json["APICall"]["Data"].dictionaryObject {
                    onCompletionHandler(true,  JSON(r))
                }
        }
    }
```

That works fine. It gets the data and returns it to me.

I am trying to show theses results in a tableview that I get when is use the `submitSearch()` function just below this json snippet

**JSON Value**

```
{
  "Results": {
    "People": [
      {
        "Name": "John Smith",
        "Address": "123 Main Str",
        "Age": "47"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Jane Smith",
        "Address": "1234 E Main Str",
        "Age": "27"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*My search func that loads the data for the UITableView*

```
   func submitSearch() {

            MyApiClass().post(noun: "Get", verb: "People", data: data) { (isSuccessful, result) in

                //This line loads all the array result from the People object in the above json
                self.tableData = result["Results"]["People"].arrayValue

                self.title? = "\(self.tableData.count) Found"
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
```

My problem is when I am populating the table cells. I keep getting `"Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'"` and other errors when trying to access the Dictionary.

```
var tableData : Array<Any> = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let person = tableData[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary
        let name = person["Name"]

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Name: \(String(describing: name))"

        return cell
    }
```

During the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, I create a `person` object and am trying to get the Dictionary stored in the tableData at the indexPath.row

I have tried

```
 let person = tableData[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary
 let person = tableData[indexPath.row] as? [String:String]
 let person : Dictionary = tableData[indexPath.row]
```

And a multitude of others.

What am I doing wrong? How do I access the Dictionary in the array?

Comment: From my understanding of Codable, I would have to create a new class for ever API call/result. That seems like overkill. If the json data ever changes, I would have to change the container class.

Comment: If the format changes, yes, you'd have to do that. But your code expects a certain format _anyway_, does it not? And a JSON API that can change the API suddenly behind your back is not a very good API anyway, is it? These considerations have not stopped everyone _else_ from updating to Decodable, so it's a little hard to see how they constitute a valid excuse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `tableData[indexPath.row]` isn't a dictionary, so you can't use `as` to convert the reference. You need to use `tableData[indexPath.row].dictionaryValue`, which returns a `[String : AnyObject]?`.

I think your code would then look something like this:

```
let person = tableData[indexPath.row].dictionaryValue
let name = person?["Name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'"

This error appears because you haven't passed any type for dictionary. Use `as! Dictionary<String, Any>` rather than `as! Dictionary`.

You can define your `tableData` as:

```
    var tableData: Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = []
```

Or rather, update your code with existing `tableData` declaration as:

```
    let person = tableData[0] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
    let name = (person?["name"] as? String) ?? ""
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Name: \(name)"
```

Or with better error handling,

```
    if let person = tableData[0] as? Dictionary<String, Any>, let name = person["name"] as? String {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Name: \(name)"
    }
```